# Как без ошибок получить страницу через CURL и отследить редирект?

Tags: php, curl

Имеется такой код получения страницы.
При попытке получить первый url, срабатывает редирект и переменные `$error` и `$response_string` пустые.

Каким образом получить содержимое страницы и удостоверится в том что был редирект?

```
    $url = "https://kamin.ru/katalog/kaminy_oblicovki/vstroennye/oblicovka_smile_80_screen80_edilkamin/";
    #$url = "https://kamin.ru/katalog/dymohody/modul_nye_dymohody_iz_nerzhaveyuwej_stali/dvustennye_rastrubno-profil_noe_soedinenie/yubka_na_trubu_v50r_d115_215_nerzh304_vulkan/";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    $error = curl_error($curl);

    $response_string = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$url = "https://kamin.ru/katalog/kaminy_oblicovki/vstroennye/oblicovka_smile_80_screen80_edilkamin/";
#$url = "https://kamin.ru/katalog/dymohody/modul_nye_dymohody_iz_nerzhaveyuwej_stali/dvustennye_rastrubno-profil_noe_soedinenie/yubka_na_trubu_v50r_d115_215_nerzh304_vulkan/";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); //TRUE для следования любому заголовку "Location: ", отправленному сервером в своем ответе (учтите, что это происходит рекурсивно, PHP будет следовать за всеми посылаемыми заголовками "Location: ", за исключением случая, когда установлена константа CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS).  
$error = curl_error($curl);

$response_string = curl_exec($curl);
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_COUNT)); // Количество редиректов. Если 0, значит не было. Если не 0, то выведет количество редиректов.

print_r(curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL)); // Получаем url перенаправления
curl_close($curl);

print_r($response_string); // Выводим страницу.
```